# Spring RestTemplate: How to reach state to check #is4xxClientError, instead of RestClientException 1st?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, http-status-codes

In my experience, after calling Spring's `RestTemplate#exchange` that subsequently receives '404 - Not Found' response, a `RestClientException` is thrown instead of returning a `ResponseEntity` that can have its status checked (i.e: with `ResponseEntity#getStatusCode#is4xxClientError`).

I don't understand why `HttpStatus#is4xxClientError` even exists if instead an `Exception` is thrown that prevents returning a `ResponseEntity` with `HttpStatus` to call #`is4xxClientError` on...

I'm reasonably convinced what I just described is the actual situation, because I can find other accounts on the internet that confirm that (i.e: [Spring MVC - RestTemplate launch exception when http 404 happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194014/spring-mvc-resttemplate-launch-exception-when-http-404-happens/)).

**How can I get to a state in Java code using `RestTemplate` where I can indeed check `ResponseEntity#getStatusCode#is4xxClientError`  when `RestTemplate#exchange` receives 404, rather than being prevented by the `RestClientException`?**  Is it something to do with `RestTemplate` configuration?

Or am I correct that is not actually possible, and maybe the existence of `ResponseEntity#getStatusCode#is4xxClientError` is actually a 'bug'?

Comment: Where is this method defined `ResponseEntity#is4xxClientError`. I didn't find it https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Comment: Sorry you're right:  It's a method on HttpStatus.  So you would call like this:  responseEntity.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError();

Comment: Code in question corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RestTemplate** has a method

```
public void setErrorHandler(ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler);
```

And **ResponseErrorHandler** interface look like this.

```
public interface ResponseErrorHandler {

    boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException;

    void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException;
}
```

Whenever **RestTemplate** processes a response, it first call **ResponseErrorHandler#hasError()**, if it returns true, **ResponseErrorHandler#handleError()** is called which may throw exception.

If you don't set **ResponseErrorHandler#setErrorHandler()**, it defaults to [DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java).
Default implementation treats 4xx / 5xx series status code as error and throws RestClientException (not this exception but subclasses of this exception).

You can always write your own **ResponseErrorHandler** and override the default behavior. So this way you can get a **ResponseEntity** object even in case of 4xx / 5xx (by writing your own implementation of `ResponseErrorHandler` and returning always `false` from the method `hasError()`).

Once you have `ResponseEntity` object, you can use **ResponseEntity#getStatusCode()#is4xxClientError()** method for the same purpose.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it sounds like it makes sense - along the lines of RestTemplate configuration that I suspected.  So I'm Accepting this Answer, thanks!